# PHP 7 error 500 internal

Tags: php

I'm completely lost with an "500 internal server error".
Yesterday I updated to PHP 7.1.2 and then there were a lot of errors.

I solved them almost all except for this strange coding error.
When trying to find the problem I echoed some output to the screen.
And this is what happens:

```
for($iRecordNumber=0;$iRecordNumber==$iTotalAssignments;$iRecordNumber++){
    $iNextRecordNumber = $iRecordNumber+1;        
    echo $iNextRecordNumber;
    echo $aAssignments[$iRecordNumber][2];
    echo $aAssignments[$iNextRecordNumber][2];
}
```

With this code I get the "500-error".

When I comment out the line with `echo $aAssignments[$iNextRecordNumber][2];` the error is gone and it does what it should do. Showing me a record from the nested array `$aAssignments(PDO query)`.

```
for($iRecordNumber=0;$iRecordNumber==$iTotalAssignments;$iRecordNumber++){
    $iNextRecordNumber = $iRecordNumber+1;        
    echo $iNextRecordNumber;
    echo $aAssignments[$iRecordNumber][2];
    // echo $aAssignments[$iNextRecordNumber][2];
}
```

I looked through the [Backward compatabilty list](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php) but did not find anything.

And the tool [codechecker](http://phpcodechecker.com/) says it's good too.

I dont know how this is possible.

What can I do to find an answer? Are there any programs or code checkers to check for more php 7 errors in my code. I have several php sites running and I do not want to check all code manually for errors.

Comment: I don't get the logic. It looks like that `for` loop will be executed only once, and only if `$iTotalAssignments` is 0. Maybe you meant to use `<` instead of `==`.

Comment: besides what @this.lau_ said. check out your server log , or even enable your php displaying errors , `ini_set("display_errors", 1);error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: @this.lau, you where correct about "<" but the post did not except the "<" and left the rest out of the message.
 and HassanAhmed Ini_set didn't report the error. Instead I used the new try{ } catch(error $e){ echo $e->getmessage();}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP's white screen of death](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475297/phps-white-screen-of-death)

Answer (score 0):

I think `$aAssignments[$iNextRecordNumber][2]` is not always set.
You could replace:

```
echo $aAssignments[$iNextRecordNumber][2];
```

By:

```
echo $aAssignments[$iNextRecordNumber][2]?? '';
```

I hope it could help.

Answer (score -1):

In PHP 7 is the error handling completly revised. A fatal error other errors no longer stops the script. To find these kind of errors, use the new error() method in the try and catch class. For example:

```
try{
   code to test on errors
} catch(error $eCatchedError) { 
    echo get_class($eCatchedError)."<br>".$eCatchedError->getLine()."<br>".$eCatchedError->getFile()."<br>".$eCatchedError->getMessage();    
} // End try and catch
```

By this way you get an more elegant way of showing an error (with css and everything)

Comment: JFYI, you should never reveal system internals outside. Neither with CSS nor without.